# Removing trailing periods from folders in a directory using powershell?

Tags: powershell, rename, directory, file-rename

Essentially I have a few hundred folders that have trailing periods at the end of the folder names because of my company's cloud service Box.com.

We're trying to remove the periods using a powershell script but admittedly my powershell knowledge is in its beginner stages.

```
$string = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} | Select Name
$string2 = Trim($string)
$string.Length
$string3 = $string.TrimEnd(".")
dir | ? { $string } | % { mv $_ -Destination ($_.Name.$string3) }
```

So above I am running the first line from within the folder in question to get the PSIsContainer names, then trimming them of white spaces, and then attempting to trim the end where I have my $string3 variable of any trailing periods in the PSIsContainer names. It's throwing an error though, and I can't figure out why.

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'TrimEnd'.
At line:1 char:27
+ $string3 = $string.TrimEnd <<<< (".")
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (TrimEnd:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$string` is an array of directory names, not a string.  You can't `TrimEnd()` an array.

You'll probably need to create a `foreach` loop to do what you want with each directory.

```psh
$Directories = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ? {$_.PSIsContainer}
foreach($Dir in $Directories)
{
    Rename-Item $Dir Trim($Dir.Name)
    Rename-Item $Dir $Dir.Name.TrimEnd(".")
}
```

Comment: Ideally, before renaming the directory you would check to see if it needs to be renamed, as you'll get an error message if the "new" name is the same as the current name.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you so much! That worked! I should have figured there would need to be a foreach loop, that's what I get for overthinking the problem! Thank you!

Comment: String methods can be cascaded, so if you want to trim leading/trailing whitespace and then a trailing dot you could do it like this: `$Dir.Name.Trim().TrimEnd('.')`.

Answer (score 1):

Still another way, if you are looking for a one-liner and if regex is not your friend:

```
ls -Rec -Dir -Incl '*.' | % { $_.MoveTo($_.FullName.Trim().TrimEnd('.')) }
```

If the pattern is simple enough, you can let the `-Include` parameter of `Get-ChildItem` do the filtering for you.

**Edit**: The `-Include` parameter does only work in combination with `-Recurse`.

Comment: Filtering via `-Include '*.'` doesn't work. You need a filter like `... | ? { $_.Name -like '*.' } | ...`.

Comment: What makes you think so @AnsgarWiechers? Filtering files with `Get-ChildItem -Include` works just fine. I'm using it all the time. It also saves you the extra pipe and often makes your code more readable.

Comment: Ah I forgot to mention that `-Include` does only work in combination with `-Recurse`. Perhaps you forgot this parameter in your test?

Comment: I tested `Get-ChildItem 'D:\test' -Recurse -Directory -Include '*.'` where `D:\test` is a folder containing some subfolders with and some without tailing dot. Only got "could not find item" errors. What PowerShell version are you using? I tested with version 4.

Comment: To my knowledge `Get-ChildItem` does not throw exceptions, if it cannot find files that match the include-pattern. It does however throw one, if it cannot read the path that you provided. Can you navigate to 'D:\test' in your PowerShell and run `Get-ChildItem` there without providing an explicit path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79277/discussion-between-manuel-batsching-and-ansgar-wiechers).

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```psh
$pattern = '^\s*(.*?)\.+\s*$'
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory |
  ? { $_.Name -match $pattern } |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace $pattern, '$1' }
```

Comment: This wont work as expected in all cases: `'   foo...  ' -replace '^\s*(.*)\.+\s*$', '$1'` will result in `foo..` because of the greedy star-quantifier, which will match also as many of the dots as it can get. You can avoid this behavior by using `^\s*(.*?)\.+\s*$` instead.

Comment: Also your approach will throw an "RenameItemIOError" exception for each element, that does not need to be renamed, as `Rename-Item` does not allow you to use identical source and destination paths. `Move-Item` would be a better choice here.